# "expand" with "takeWhile", also applying a limit, like "take" does

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to fetch all the pages until there's either no more pages or some limit (say 10 pages) is reached.

If I go this way:

```
obs.pipe(expand((page) => {
    return service.call(page).nextPage;
}), 
take(10), 
takeWhile(morePages));
```

Then the take 10 always happens. If I go this way:

```
obs.pipe(expand((page) => {
    return service.call(page).nextPage;
}), 
takeWhile(morePages),
take(10));
```

then it may call far more than 10 times.

The other choice is I write my own takeWhile that includes its own counter. I'll do it that way but I'm hoping I can build that device using standard rxjs options.

Comment: Its hard to understand what your code does. The title says you have an expand, while the code samples don't. Please, update the question to reflect the whole situation. Also, a playground example is often helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe isn't correct. Both `take` and `takeWhile` complete the chain when a certain condition is met. When subscriber receives a `complete` notification it disposes the chain so it doesn't matter which `take*` completes first. It will always complete the chain.

So in fact it doesn't matter in which order you use `take(10)` and `takeWhile(morePages)`. The functionality is always the same.

Comment: The expand won't signal completion though? It just runs forever, that's what I'm using take / takeWhile to interrupt. I updated my incomplete code sample though.

Comment: Whether or not `expand` emits `complete` notification depends on what `service.call(page).nextPage` returns